# Removing interior loops of a network

Tags: python, networkx

I have a large graph that consists of many self loops. I am trying to remove all of the interior loops so that I'm left with only one large (exterior) loop.  Is there any way to find all edges within a given loop?  I've tried using `graph.nodes_with_selfloops()` and `graph.selfloop_edges` but neither has gotten me very far.

Comment: You should show your existing code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way to tackle this problem using the networkx.algorithms library:

```
import networkx as netx
import networkx.algorithms as al

# build graph
g = netx.DiGraph()
edges = [(1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(4,1),(1,2),(2,5),(5,3),(3,4),(4,1)]
g.add_edges_from(edges)

# find cycles
cycles = al.simple_cycles(g)

# assuming that the exterior cycle will contain the most nodes
for cycle in cycles:
    print len(cycle)
```

Result should be:

>>> 5

>>> 6